# How do I hide menus with Big Cartel

Tags: css, html, bigcartel

I have a custom theme that I did not make, I was wondering if there was anyway to make it so I can hide menu items (so they don't show up on the menu bar). Maybe something in the stylesheet to dictate it? Please help!

```
 <div id="store" class="clearfix">

  <div id="header">

  <h2 id="logo" {% if theme.image != blank %}class="image"{% endif %}><a href="/" id="store_home" title="{{ store.name | escape }}">{% if theme.image != blank %}<img height="35"src="{{ theme.image.url }}" />{% endif %}</a></h2>

        <div id="top-pages">
    <ul>
      <li>{{ pages.home | link_to }}</li>{% for page in pages.all %}<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endfor %}<li>{{ pages.contact | link_to }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- #top-pages -->
```

Comment: If you have access to the style sheet, you can easily set the unwanted items to `display: none`, but it's better to alter the HTML if possible.

Comment: I do have access to the style sheet.. where exactly would I put that? The way Bigcartel is setup.. it has a list of all pages you created then the theme files.. so would I need to add that to the head of the individual page?

Comment: <div id="store" class="clearfix">
  
      <div id="header">

      <h2 id="logo" {% if theme.image != blank %}class="image"{% endif %}><a href="/" id="store_home" title="{{ store.name | escape }}">{% if theme.image != blank %}<img height="35"src="{{ theme.image.url }}" />{% endif %}</a></h2>
      
            <div id="top-pages">
        <ul>
          <li>{{ pages.home | link_to }}</li>{% for page in pages.all %}<li>{{ page | link_to }}</li>{% endfor %}<li>{{ pages.contact | link_to }}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        
      <!-- #top-pages -->

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell you what to hide without you posting some of the code on here but why don't you just 'display: none;' the menu li?

```
*menu-item* {display: none;} //where menu item is the path to the menu item
```

Comment: Where would I put this?

Comment: you'd put this in the templates main css file